# How to efficiently check if any one of a set of attributes has changed before_save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to exclude timestamp updating for a large set of attributes of a class.  The permit timestamp updating set is equally large, so it's not a matter of selecting between them.

How can I shrink something like the following?:

```
  def determine_timestamp_update
    if self.attr_1_changed?|| self.attr_2_changed? || ... || ... || ...
      self.class.record_timestamps = false
    else
      self.class.record_timestamps = true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
def determine_timestamp_update
  attrs = %w[ attr_1 attr_2 attr_3 ... ]

  self.class.record_timestamps = attrs.none? {|attr| changes[attr] }
end
```

The `changes` method [returns a Hash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) of attributes that have changed. We use [`Enumerable#none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F) to check each of the given attributes—it will return `false` if `changes[attr]` is truthy for any of `attrs`.